# How to prove that $|F(z)|\le A e^{B |z|^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $$\large F:\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$$ $$\large F(z)=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-e^{-2\pi n}\cdot e^{2\pi i z })$$

How to prove that $$\large|F(z)|\le A  e^{B  |z|^2},\forall z \in \mathbb{C}$$

where $\large A>0$ , $\large B>0$ are constants. Note that $\large F$ is an entire function.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ |F(z)| = \left(\prod_{n=1}^{[2|z|]} |\text{stuff}|\right) \times \left(\prod_{n=[2|z|]+1}^\infty |\text{stuff}| \right).$$
Show that second product is uniformly bounded (e.g. by taking logs).  Find a crude bound on the first product (e.g. bound the first term and raise it to the power of $[2|z|]$).  Here $[x]$ denotes the integer part function.